# Visual Studio 2015 automatically include missing includes

Tags: c++, plugins, visual-studio-2015, add-in

I wanted to ask if anyone of you knows if there is a setting or plugin for Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise to automatically include any missing things, example if a namespace is missing or if "endl" is missing it includes the class.
Thanks!

Comment: How would the plugin know that you intended to add a namespace or write `endl`, but forgot?

Comment: The Addon [VisualAssist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) can add includes, so does [Reshaper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/features/). Both cost money, however. I think as a student you can get Reshaper for free and Visual Assist for 50 bucks with updates for six months. Be aware that they might not find the correct include file if functions with the same name exist in different source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not only can I not find / am not aware of such a plugin - I doubt it will ever exist.

The problem comes that without knowing every include file on your computer (which is a very time consuming/hard process), how could said plugin know which one you wanted?

Example:
I have marmalade (A cross platform development tool), Cygwin-Dev (A windows unix-shell), a GCC-cross compiler and visual-studio installed.
This means my computer has four (if not more) versions of "iostream", as well as several different implementations of the standard library (for different platforms).

How could such an add in know "which" include I wanted?

Personal opinion:
I understand what you are looking for, but honestly - even if such a tool did exist, I would advise against using it. when you get beyond simple example "hello world" programs and alike, C++ include files become a non-trivial subject. A single project I am involved in professionally has near two-thousand header-files, ranging from Iostream, though to third-party libraries, and near a thousand home-grown files.
Managing and understanding what to include and where is an essential skill of the C++ programmer, and quickly becomes second nature.

P.S.
Remember that every function on sites such as [en.cppreference.com/w/](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) will state at the top of the page what header file you need to include them. Reading such reference pages will (also) become second nature in due time.

Comment: Agreed. But we could at least have this for standard libraries.. Maybe someday.